# Causes of rapidly-progressing myopia

Tags: eye, vision, optometry, myopia-nearsightedness, opthalmology

Imagine a patient, say, Steve. Steve is 19 years old, and began experiencing signs of myopia at 10 or so. He spent years wearing glasses on and off, and progressed to a -1.5 prescription (with a difference of roughly 0.5 between the two eyes) by age 17. Then, his myopia progression began to accelerate. Within six months, he had a -2.0 prescription (averaged across the two, still 0.5 difference). By age 18, he had a -3.0 prescription; by age 19, a -4.0 prescription. Obvious resources discuss rapid-progression myopia, but not its causes. What would cause such rapid change?

Sample Background Information:

- Both his parents have low-level myopia (-1.5 to -2)
- Siblings have low-level myopia

Comment: Regarding "Obvious resources discuss rapid-progression myopia, but not its causes." -- tried google scholar as in https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=lens+induced+myopia ?